# Python SqlAlchemy Google Cloud Sql connectionevent loop error closed

Tags: python, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to connect with my Google Cloud Sql db using google.cloud.sql.connector, and this is the code to connect:

```
def getconn():
    with Connector() as connector:
        conn = connector.connect(
            instance_connection_name,
            "pg8000",
            user = db_user,
            password = db_pass,
            db = db_name,
            ip_type = IPTypes.PUBLIC
        )
        return conn


# create connection pool
pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    "postgresql+pg8000://",
    creator=getconn
)
```

and this is the code to do a simple select:

```
with pool.connect() as db_conn:
    # insert into database
    #db_conn.execute(insert_stmt, parameters={"id": "book1", "title": "Book One"})

    # query database
    result = db_conn.execute(sqlalchemy.text("SELECT * from users")).fetchall()

    # Do something with the results
    for row in result:
        print(row)
connector.close()
```

now when i run the code, the connection are ok and i print all records of table into db, but after i receive this error:

```
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000026D24CD0A60>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 750, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000026D24CD0A60>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 750, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by the fact that your calling `connector.close()` on a context manager object.

When using the [connector as a context manager](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector#using-connector-as-a-context-manager) you do not need to explicitly close the connector object, the context manager does this for you. You only need to call `connector.close()` when you explicitly [initialize the connector object WITHOUT a context manager](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector#how-to-use-this-connector) like so:

```py
from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector

connector = Connector()
# your database connection/pooling code
# ...
connector.close
```

So for your specific case just remove your `connector.close()` call and you will no longer see the error.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is on Windows SO, so I have fixed using module platform and asyncio, with this snippet code:

```
import platform
if platform.system()=='Windows':
   asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
```

Comment: See answer I provided, I don't believe this error is caused by Windows.

Comment: Hi Jack, i have the same error removing connector, but i have fixed setting this policy. Probably there is somthing wrong on my machine